# How to view edit view inside the modal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, bootstrap-modal

I've tried so many ways to load the 'edit' partial view inside my modal but still no luck for it. I'm new to MVC, I've tried to do CRUD operation inside the modal window. Without modal i can perform CRUD operation. Now i want to do CRUD operation inside the modal window.

This my Script section

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click', '#edit', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Companies/_Edit',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#createCompanyFormModalbody').html(data);
                    $('#createCompanyFormModal').modal('show');
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("There is some problem in the service!");
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

This is my Edit Partial view

```
@model Mvc.Models.Company

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Company</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CompanyID)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.URL, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.URL, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.URL, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Active, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Active)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Active, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tstamp, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tstamp, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tstamp, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsDeleted, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsDeleted)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsDeleted, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

This is my Controller class

```
   public ActionResult _Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Company company = db.Companies.Find(id);
            if (company == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            // return View(company);
            return PartialView(company);
        }

        // POST: Companies/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult _Edit([Bind(Include = "CompanyID,Name,Address,PhoneNumber,URL,Email,Active,Tstamp,IsDeleted")] Company company)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(company).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(company);
        }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. To get a better response, it would be good to explain what is going wrong... and if possible narrow down/clarify the requirement.

Comment: `return PartialView(company)` is that a cshtml? A view?

Comment: @HoomanBahreini I want to perform crud operation inside a modal window. I'm new to MVC. Can you help me?